# Wordpress "wp cron event run" as Siteground cron job

Tags: plugins, wp-cron, cron, ssh

Is there a syntax that will allow me to run "wp cron event run" as a Siteground cron job?

I found this example that runs through a third party application.  I'm wondering if this command can be run as a Siteground cron job:
$ wp cron event run --all --ssh=cale17.sg-host.com/home/customer/www/cale17.sg-host.com/public_html

I've tried several iterations, and I get this error:

Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
The used path is: /home/customer/mydomain.com/
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SiteGround here. It's great that you're exploring running "wp cron event run" as a SiteGround cron job. To ensure a smooth process, we recommend following the steps outlined in our tutorial on how to replace WordPress Cron with a real Cron job. It provides detailed instructions to help you set up your SiteGround cron job correctly. You can find the tutorial here:

https://siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/real-cron-job/

If you encounter any issues or have further questions, feel free to contact our support team for direct assistance.

Best regards,
The SiteGround Team

Comment: The siteground cron job is working well.  Thanks!